# What is the plausability/legitimacy of the San Andreas Fault 'Big One' Megaquake mechanism?

Tags: earthquakes, models, predictability, seismic-hazards

In the ScienceAlert article "[New estimates suggest the 'big one' in San Andreas could be much worse than we thought](http://www.sciencealert.com/new-estimates-suggest-the-big-one-in-san-andreas-could-be-much-worse-than-we-thought)" they make the claim that:

> Researchers have forecast a mega-quake running the entirety of the San Andreas fault line in California

A major mechanism suggested for this quake is the "creeping zone" of the fault, which is defined in the article as:

> The "creeping section" of the San Andreas fault that Page refers to above is a 153-km (95-mile) stretch that bridges the northern and southern segments of the fault.

The article reports that recent modelling has determined that it was possible (just not all that probable) that:

> Seismic activity in this creeping section could help trigger a much larger earthquake, enabling a major quake originating on either side to span the north-south divide.

Researching further (as I know better than to trust news sources), in the USGS publication that the article was based on, "[The Uniform California Earthquake Rupture Forecast,
Version 3 (UCERF3)—The Time-Independent Model](http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2013/1165/pdf/ofr2013-1165.pdf)", it is still not entirely clear as to how the 'creeping section' of the San Andreas Fault could cause this mega-quake. Hence the question:

**What specifically changed in our understanding of the seismicity of the 'creeping section' to claim that it could be a mechanism for a San Andreas megaquake?**

*I would not be surprised if it is related to the research going on behind [simultaneous and near-simultaneous earthquakes](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/9078/7009) in general*